# Normal form of a surjective Linear map

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry, differential-geometry, linear-transformations

Let $L:\mathbb{R}^n\to\mathbb{R}^m$ a linear surjective map. I Have to prove that there exist a linear isomorphism $\psi: \mathbb{R}^n\to\mathbb{R}^n$ such that $L(\psi(x_1,...,x_n))=(x_1,...,x_m)$ for all $(x_1,\dots,x_n)\in\mathbb{R}^n$.

**Proof** First of all I notice that $n\ge m$ and that the dimension of $Ker(L)$ is $n-m$ since L is surjective. Let W be a direct complement of $Ker(L)$, i.e. $\mathbb{R}^n=W\oplus Ker(L)$. Let $\{w_1,\dots,w_m\}$ and $\{v_1,\dots,v_{n-m}\}$ bases respectively of $W$ and $Ker(L)$. I don't know how to define $\psi$.

Can you help me, please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So let $\mathbb{R}^n=W\oplus\operatorname{Ker}(L)$.
Let $e_1,\ldots,e_m$ and $e'_1,\ldots,e'_n$ be the standard bases in $\mathbb{R}^m$ and $\mathbb{R}^n$ respectively. Since $L(W)=\mathbb{R}^m$ we can choose vectors $w_1,\ldots,w_m\in W$ such that $L(w_1)=e_1,\ldots,L(w_m)=e_m$.

Let $w_{m+1},\ldots,w_n$ be a basis $\operatorname{Ker}(L)$. Then $w_1,\ldots,w_n$ is a basis $\mathbb{R}^n$. Construct a linear operator $\psi:\,\mathbb{R}^n\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^n$ such that $\psi(e'_i)=w_i$, $1\leq i\leq n$.

We have $L(\psi(e'_i))=L(w_i)=e_i$ if $i\leq m$ and $=0$ if $i>m$.
Hence, $\psi$ is the required linear operator.

Comment: Thank you very much!